# CNN for non-image data

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a model from this https://machinelearningmastery.com/cnn-models-for-human-activity-recognition-time-series-classification/ example that takes as inputs 3 (to unbug, there will be 1000s) inputs which are arrays of dimension (17,40):

```
[[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 5 5 5]
  ...
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]]
```

the output is a single integer between 0 and 8:

```
[[6]
 [3]
 [1]]
```

I use a CNN as follows:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Xo, Yo)
print("Xtrain", X_train)
print("Y_train", y_train)
print("Xtest", X_test)
print("Y_test", y_test)
print("X_train.shape[1]", X_train.shape[1])
print("X_train.shape[2]", X_train.shape[2])
#print("y_train.shape[1]", y_train.shape[1])
verbose, epochs, batch_size = 1, 10, 10
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

it gives me the following error:
ValueError: You are passing a target array of shape (6, 1)
but in fact it should take only 1 value as output.
Why do I have such error message when it is only supposed to take 1 value as output ?

Comment: Why do I have such error message when it is only supposed to take 1 value as output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Softmax layer size should be equal to the number of classes. Your Softmax layer has only 1 output.
For this classification problem, first of all, you should turn your targets to a [one-hot encoded](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/target-encoding-vs-one-hot-encoding-with-simple-examples-276a7e7b3e64) format, then edit the size of the Softmax layer to the number of classes.

Comment: I changed the last dense to 9 because I have 9 classes. When I launch a predict, it gives me 9 values which I believe are the nodes for each class. How can I have only 1 output which is the class ?

Comment: Those are the probabilities of each class..You can use argmax function to identify the predicted class.